# Add text to label(not changing) in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, label

Is it possible to add on to the text of a label without changing existing text? I'm new to mac development in Xcode so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no. Basically, you replace the text with a new string that includes the old text

```
self.myLabel.text = [self.myLabel.text stringByAppendingString:@"more stuff"];
```